# Expected end of line but found "/"

Tags: bash, script

I am updating a script that was written by someone previously in my position but it will not compile due to the error above.

This is my first time using AppleScript, so I am very much a beginner. I had originally copy and pasted the code, but in case the quotes and other characters got "prettified" I typed it out myself. This did not fix the issue, and it seems to lie within the first few lines of the script. When shortening the script to the following lines I still get the error.

```
#!/bin/sh
*Change computer name and local name to TechLoaner in case changed by user*
/usr/sbin/scutil --set ComputerName TechLoaner
/usr/sbin/scutil --set LocalHostName techloaner
echo Set machine name to TechLoaner
#cleanup local User’s home dir
rm -rf ~/Desktop/*
rm -rf ~/Documents/*
rm -rf ~/Downloads/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/*
rm -rf ~/Movies/*
rm -rf ~/Music/*
rm -rf ~/Pictures/*
rm -rf ~/Public/Drop\ Box/*
rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
echo Cleaned up local User’s home directory
#clean up global caches and temp data
rm -rf /Library/Caches/*
rm -rf /System/Library/Caches/*
rm -rf /Users/Shared/*
echo Cleaned up global caches and temp data
#log cleanup.  We touch the log file after removing it since syslog
#won't create missing logs
rm /private/var/log/alf.log
touch /private/var/log/alf.log
rm /private/var/log/cups/access_log
touch /private/var/log/cups/access_log
rm /private/var/log/cups/error_log
touch /private/var/log/cups/error_log
rm /private/var/log/cups/page_log
touch /private/var/log/cups/page_log
rm /private/var/log/daily.out
rm /private/var/log/ftp.log*
touch /private/var/log/ftp.log
rm /private/var/log/lpr.log*
rm /private/var/log/mail.log*
touch /private/var/log/lpr.log
rm /private/var/log/mail.log*
touch /private/var/log/mail.log
rm /private/var/log/monthly.out
rm /private/var/log/run_radmind.log
rm /private/var/log/secure.log
touch /private/var/log/secure.log
rm /private/var/log/system.log*
touch /private/var/log/system.log
rm /private/var/log/weekly.out
rm /private/var/log/windowserver.log
touch /private/var/log/windowserver.log
echo Log file cleanup completed
echo Setting Chrome to Use the Standard MacOS Print Window now....
cp com.google.Chrome.plist ~/Library/Preferences/
defaults write com.google.Chrome DisablePrintPreview -bool true
echo Success!
lpstat -p | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -I{} lpadmin -x {}
echo Reset printing system completed
networksetup -removeallpreferredwirelessnetworks en0
echo Removed all WiFi SSIDs
rm -rf /Users/*/Library/Keychains
#sudo security -q delete-keychain /Library/Keychains/System.keychain
echo Cleaned WiFi keychain
echo Success!
echo  Please quit this app and logout now...
exit
```

Comment: @Allan copied the source code from a .txt file that the previous guy had left near the .exe file. Assuming this is all AppleScript since we only use Macs here and it was using terminal commands. Error highlights the first "/" in the line /usr/sbin/scutil

Comment: That's not AppleScript - it's `sh`, the rudimentary command line interpreter.  I think we're missing a lot here.  This file was found "near the .exe files"?  Did you find this on a PC or on a Mac/Linux computer?  What are you using to edit this file now?

Comment: @Allan there was a package of files on one of the loaner macs labeled "Loaner cleanup" Opened the package and found 2 folders. One was labeled "mac" which contains an executable, and the other labeled resources, which has an executable and some resource files. Also had an .icns file. In the shared drive (on one of our office PCs) was the source code, which I copied into Apple's Script Editor software. Not too experienced with software engineering and I'm only interning here for the summer so I don't know too much about the other background of this script.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this script? If you're just trying to get a 'clean' Mac, there are easier and better ways. You're deleting several default folders in the User home, which may be resistant to deletion. I'm not sure you can delete all those logs, without sudo at the least. The second line ought to be a `#` comment.

Comment: This is scripting; software engineering is a totally different topic.  It's the difference between riding a bike and driving an F1 race car.  You need to articulate what your did exactly (respond to the questions asked), explain what you did *exactly*,  and articulate what you're trying to accomplish.  Keep in mind, we can't see over your shoulder.

Comment: @benwiggy It just deletes folder content, not the folders themselves. The part after cleaning up the user home will fail though.

Comment: @nohillside Oh, yes. It's still the wrong way to go about the whole process, though.

Comment: _it will not compile_ : sh is not a compiler, so it won't compile anything. Perhaps you mean a parsing error. Now, while there are several obvious errors in the script, which you can see when you paste it into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), I don't see a structural error as the one you have mentioned. Show a screenshot of how you run the script, and the error message you get. I would expect a _*Change : command not found_  error.

Comment: Note however, that even if you fix the errors, the script is quite dangerous. If the `scutil` fails, it will clean your own home directory.

Comment: @user1934428 It will clean the home directory irregardless whether scutil fails or not.

Comment: @nohillside : Ah, right you are. So this seems to be the purpose of this script then ....

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT RUN THIS SCRIPT** (see PS: for why)

This is a shell script, not an AppleScript, so pasting it into Apple Script Editor will for sure lead to errors.

To run this, you would copy it to your Mac as `~/Downloads/techloaner.sh`, open Terminal and enter `sh ~/Downloads/techloaner.sh` followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>.

PS: In general, I advise against running scripts (or any code) you are not familiar with. For the one above you will get quite a few "permission denied" errors and `rm -rf /Users/*/Library/Keychains` would create problems for all users.